# Jquery datatables totalling columns where the value is rendered as a hyerpilnk

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the DataTables 1.10.11 with the .sum() plugin option.

I can get the sum to work and total if the column is a number.  My problem is that a lot of the columns have been rendered as hyperlinks to allow a drill-down.  When I sum on these, the result is Nan.

Anyone have any ideas how to work-around this.

The below code works on column 13, as this is not rendered.  Columns 3-12 fail.

```
        $('#tblDebtors').dataTable({
              "autoWidth":false
            , "drawCallback": function() {
                    var api = this.api();

                    // Total over all pages
                    var total = api.column(13).data().sum();

                    $(api.column(13).footer()).html(fncFmtNbr(total,2,"Y","Y"));
                }
            , "footer": true
            , "info":false
            , "JQueryUI":true
            , "ordering":true
            , "paging":false
            , "scrollY":"470px"
            , "scrollX":"1485px"
            , "scrollCollapse":true
            , "columnDefs": [
                        { className: "Left", "targets": [ 0,1 ] }
                    ,   { className: "Center", "targets": [ 2 ] }
                    ,   { className: "Right", "targets": [ 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 ] }
                    ,   {"targets": 3,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Current_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[3]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ,   {"targets": 4,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Pd1_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[4]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ,   {"targets": 5,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Pd2_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[5]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ,   {"targets": 6,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Pd3_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[6]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ,   {"targets": 7,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Pd4_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[7]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ,   {"targets": 8,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Pd5_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[8]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ,   {"targets": 9,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Pd6_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[9]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ,   {"targets": 10,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Pd7_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[10]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ,   {"targets": 11,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Older_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[11]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ,   {"targets": 12,
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<a id="href_Total_'+row[0]+'" href="#">'+row[12]+'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                ]
        });
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a demo to play with. Did you try to look at `api.column(13).data()` values ? I'm wondering if it is not taking the HTML element containing the value instead of just the value you're willing to add up.

Comment: HI.  I think the problem is that the API is reading the html in the cell.  The HTML is <a....>100.00</a> and not 100.00.  So I guess I'm trying to work out how to get the contents of the <a ></a> totalled.

Comment: Could you provide us the data you have inside `api.column(13).data()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you using something like [this](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()), if so alter it like this for you use case:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('sum()', function (){
    return this.flatten().reduce(function(a, b){
        if (typeof a === 'string') {
            a = a.text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
        }
        if (typeof b === 'string') {
            b = b.text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
        }
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
});
```

Please note, without a sample JSFiddle it's difficult to test this approach but basically we're after the text within the anchor. Rather than multiplying it by 1 we could parseInt it with a decimal radix or simple do a `~~`...

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, that's the datatables_sum.js script.  So I guess I need to strip the <a ..></a> wrapper off the cell contents.

Comment: Nope, I altered it to: `a = a.text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;`, but after thinking about it you probably need to do this instead: `a = $(a).text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;`